# webserver on VPS (Ubuntu or Debian)

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mysql, php, debian

I have a VPS server, I want create a webserver, and host php, ruby sites. What do you think, i need a isp control panel or lampp server (xampp for linux) is enough?
I have some domain names and I want redirect they the new server, how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do *not* use lampp, xampp, or any of the other bundled LAMP stacks. Those are meant for development only, not for production use. The maintainers of these bundled stacks configure the server applications as to stay out of the way of the development process. This works great for development, but leaves you open to many security issues if used in production.

It should be easy enough to install a full LAMP environment using your linux distro's package repository. Edit your question to include which distro you're using and we'll be able to better point you in the right direction.

--Edit--
Since you're using Debian, you'll use the apt system to install your LAMP packages:

```
$ sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 mysql-server php5-mysql
```

Comment: I use Debian based distros

Comment: What do you think, ISPConfig it's a better way? This is knowing all lamp feature + dns, mail and ftp server

Comment: I've never used ISPConfig, so I can't give a definitive answer. From what I can tell, ISPConfig gives you a control panel for apache/postfix/bind/etc, once they're already installed - it doesn't install the packages itself. There's a tutorial here that seems pretty comprehensive: http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-debian-lenny-ispconfig3-p3

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I know this doesn't answer your question completely. It is in reference to setting up the LAMP stack, not to the question of setting up domains to point to your VPS.

You can use the `tasksel` command to quickly install a LAMP server as well.

`sudo tasksel` will take you to an ncurses interface. Very easy.

`tasksel --list-tasks` will show the tasks available for install.
`tasksel --task-packages` will show what packages are pulled for a particular task.

`sudo tasksel install <task>` installs the task from the command line.